Weird texture glitch when using blur tool for texture painting
I had this problem for awhile now where noise tends to appear, especially around seams, when using blur tool. It can be mitigated by striking over the seem sideways instead of along the seam or minimizing tool size. I tried changing all possible brush settings to see what causes the problem, but none worked. I managed to make it less dotty by reducing spacing, but it still remains. Both texture and the blur tool has maximum extension for seams.It also tends to get better if I paint over the area with solid brush, but not always. (the texture is png image exported from Blender, edited in drawing software, imported back to Blender. I am trying to blur the seams)


Edit: after more experimenting and comparing with different presets, it looks like if blur is set to strength of 1-1.9 there are no problems. With strength of 2 random dots appear, mostly in areas of around seams or mirror axis center. With strength of 3+ it just goes bonkers a gives nothing but a color vomit of TV noise.
Any idea of how to get a blur with strength above 2 without these glitches?

You're talking about seams, without showing the mesh or UV - what seams are you talking about, exactly?

The seams in UV. The ones you get on texture where UV island meets another UV island.

But those spots don’t appear to correspond with the edges of the UV island.

They are not exactly on always on seams, it is a bit random, dotting in area around mostly. Interestingly, they are never on areas where the blur brush tip does not touch the seams. Regardless of the place where they appear, I just want to know what to do to get rid of those dots.

Strength of the brush is 0-1, where do you get this 'strength of 1.9'?

The artifacts are caused by using a power of double of the limit Blender gives you - you should be only using a power of 1 here. Multiple strokes will arrive at what you are attempting to do without tearing the pixels apart in the image - the spots are similar to what happens with changing to Sharpen at high power.

I see. Did not think of it as a limit, since it lets me change it. I thought limits were absolute.

Plenty of these sliders will allow to type higher than prescribed limit, and for the fill tool that is great if you don’t want to tap 3x, but really here you might try using a curve stroke and the enter key to repeat the stroke a few times.
